# Can I sync a task list to outlook and have the tasks show in the To-Do Bar

Tags: tasks, task-list, outlook, sync

I have a task list in SharePoint that I have synced to my Outlook. I can view the SP tasks in Outlook under My Tasks and I can create new tasks in Outlook. What I can seem to figure out is how to display the tasks from SharePoint in the To-Do Bar on the right side of Outlook (see below).

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Edit** - I am currently using SharePoint 2016 and Outlook/Office 2016 Professional

Comment: I've found when connecting a regular sharepoint 2010 task list to outlook 2010, the items assigned to me appear in the to do, and the complete list (assigned or not) is simply 100% sync'd with outlook/sharepoint.

Comment: BTW Which SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: My synced SP tasks show under Tasks, but they do not show up in the To Do  list. Everything is OOTB by the way, so the Task List is just a basic list with nothing modified

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using? as it is working same as you want in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Per my edit, I'm using SP 2016 and Outlook/Office 2016 Professional

Comment: Sorry mate, Don't have an idea about SharePoint 2016. :)

Comment: Don't know if you have sorted or not, but arrange your task by folder and the will appear

Comment: Check out this link:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3f0e9e05-37d8-4731-aa21-cde4be123572/sharepoint-tasks-not-appearing-in-todo-list?forum=outlook They say, the reason is a broken outlook profile. Try to create a new profile and it should work.